# Use Robocopy to create a 'delta' of changed files

Tags: windows, deployment, robocopy

I have a source folder  and a preprod folder .

I need to create a group of files/folders which are newer in  than on   (ie a 'delta') which will be created on an interim server . This delta of files and folders will then be deployed to preprod by a different team.

My presumption is to use Robocopy, any help appreciated.

This is on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you don't want to copy (or sync) files from ServerA to ServerB with robocopy but just be aware of what files are newer to copy them to another server (serverC). If this is the case you can use the switch /L of robocopy which just does nothing but showing you what it would do:

```
λ robocopy \\serverA\share\ \\serverB\share\ /E /L

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Herramienta para copia eficaz de archivos
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Inicio: Thu Mar 05 15:53:48 2015

   Origen : \\serverA\share\
     Destino : \\serverB\share\

    Archivos: *.*

  Opciones: *.* /L /S /E /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           2    \\serverA\share\
            Nuevo arch                        28        parabap
           Nuevo dir       1    \\serverA\share\newsubdir\
            Nuevo arch                        16        tarmac

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total   Copiado   OmitidoNo coincidencia     ERROR    Extras
Directorios:         2         1         1         0         0         0
 Archivos:         3         2         1         0         0         0
    Bytes:        53        44         9         0         0         0
    Veces:   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00

Finalizado: Thu Mar 05 15:53:49 2015
```

You can parse the "Nuevo arch" (probably in english will be "New File") and Nuevo dir (New directory) to have a list of changes.